# "Capping" a Binary Search Tree (removing all elements > cap)

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, graph-theory

I can't think of a recursive algorithm for doing this. My attempt was:

```
void capValue(Node node) {

    if (node == null)
        return

    if (node.element > cap)
        capValue(node.left)
        node = null;
    else // node.element < cap
        capValue(node.right)
}
```

However, you can't just null out nodes (in java at least, which I'd like to code this in) as that would just shift the current pointer to address 0, while the object we wanted to get rid of still has a "pointer path" to it via the root of the tree, and thus won't get garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the node from the function. It can go like this:

```
Node cap(Node node, int val)
    // There's no node. There's nothing to cap.
    if (node == null)
        return null;
    // The node and it's left subtree should stay
    if node.key <= val {
        node.right = cap(node.right, val);
        return node;
    }
    // The node and it's right subtree must be deleted,
    // so we can go to the left subtree
    return cap(node.left, val);
```

It should be called like `root = cap(root, val)` later in the code.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. We will first find the greater node and then update the parent link to null. 
If root node itself was greater than cap then null it.

```
boolean capValue(Node node) 
{
if (node == null)
    return false;

if (node.element > cap) {
node = null;
return true;            
}
else {// node.element < cap 
     if(capValue(node.right))
     node.right=null;
     return false;  
}    
}
```

Comment: With a root value of `1` and a left child of `0`, _cap_ to `0`.

Comment: In that case , the first comparison will be done by the second if block and the root will be set to null.

Comment: `the root will be set to null` - even *if* that was the case: how does the caller access the *cap*ped tree (`0`/`left`)?